# Is it possible to disable the tool pop-up when pressing Ctrl after selecting cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to disable the "helpful" pop-up that appears after one selects multiple cells in Excel?

I never, ever use this tool and it is more of of a hindrance than anything else.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to File>Options>General

Un-check "Show Quick Analysis options on selection"

[image]

Comment: L I F E S A V E R !!   Thank you.